# react-navigation nested drawer items

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I'm trying to create nested menu in react native drawer. I can create the menu as below but I have to find a way to group items and put them into accordion. This is how I currently create the menu:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { SafeAreaView, ScrollView, StyleSheet,View } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerItems,createDrawerNavigator  } from 'react-navigation';
import { Container, Content, Text, List, ListItem } from "native-base";
import {Image,ImageBackground} from "react-native";
import logo from '../images/logofullwhite200.png';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20
  }
});

const DrawerComponent = props => {
  const skippedItems = Object.keys(props.drawerItems).filter(name => props.drawerItems[name].skip);
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <Content>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{
              uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/master/assets/drawer-cover.png"
            }}
            style={{
              height: 120,
              alignSelf: "stretch",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}>
            <Image
              square
              style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
              source={logo}
            />
          </ImageBackground>
          <DrawerItems
            {...props}
            onItemPress={({ focused, route }) => {
              if (!skippedItems.includes(route.routeName)) {
                props.onItemPress({ focused, route });
              }
            }}
          />
        </Content>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

DrawerComponent.propTypes = {
  onItemPress: PropTypes.func,
  drawerItems: PropTypes.object
};

export default DrawerComponent;
```

this is the data example

```
"CreateSale": Object {
    "navigationOptions": Object {
      "drawerLabel": Object {
        "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
        "_owner": null,
        "_store": Object {},
        "key": null,
        "props": Object {
          "i18nKey": "sale.create_sale",
        },
        "ref": null,
        "type": [Function I18nextWithTranslation],
      },
    },
    "screen": [Function KeyboardAwareNavigator],
    "userInfo": Object {
      "showOnLogin": true,
    },
  },
  "Customer": Object {
    "navigationOptions": Object {
      "drawerLabel": Object {
        "$$typeof": Symbol(react.element),
        "_owner": null,
        "_store": Object {},
        "key": null,
        "props": Object {
          "i18nKey": "list.title",
        },
        "ref": null,
        "type": [Function I18nextWithTranslation],
      },
    },
    "screen": [Function KeyboardAwareNavigator],
    "userInfo": Object {
      "showOnLogin": true,
    },
  }
```

[image]

This is how index.tsx looks

```
export default new ClientModule({
  router: <MainScreenNavigator />,
  onAppCreate: [
    async (modules: ClientModule) =>
      (ref.navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
        {
          ...modules.drawerItems
        },
        {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          contentComponent: props => <DrawerComponent {...props} drawerItems={modules.drawerItems} />
        }
      ))
  ]
});
```

I have to put the items in to accordion, they have to look nested such as as below:

Outlets

- Customers
- Customer

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-nested-drawer-menu-with-react-native-a1c2fdcab6c9/ Check this out.

Comment: that's not what I need.

Answer (score -1):

no need to make nested drawer. you can use [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) and make custom drawerItem like accordion

```
yarn add react-native-collapsible
```

```
import Collapsible from 'react-native-collapsible';

() => (
  <Collapsible collapsed={isCollapsed}>
    <SomeCollapsedView />
  </Collapsible>
);
```

Comment: I know how to do that, native-base I use has collapsible as well and I used it countless times.  Problem is I can't get each item of  <DrawerItems>, I can't iterate on DrawerItems to see its contents so I can place them accordingly (nesting or using collapse). Tried createDrawerNavigator as well  but it doesn't work in this setup.

Comment: @CanerÇakmak you should update snack reproducible example so I can resolve

Comment: I don't know how to do that but if I knew, I would update the same code I pasted here. I'm  basically asking how to iterate on <DrawerItems>.